# Stop traffic to unhealthy instances without replacing them by auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Using **ELB** for TCP protocol and **AWS Auto Scaling** I run into the following problem when scaling out.

- three EC2 instances each with 2,000 connections
- scaling out because that is my specified threshold
- a new instance gets added by Auto Scaling

How can I stop now traffic going to the three EC2 instances which have too many connections?

1. Removing it from ELB will mean that it will get terminated after a maximum of 1h using connection draining. **Bad: TCP connections will get closed.**
2. Marking the EC2 instance as unhealthy using CloudWatch. **Bad: Auto Scaling will detect and replace unhealthy instances**
3. Detaching EC2 instance from Auto Scaling group manually via AWS CLI. 
   **Bad: Detaching it from Auto Scaling will also remove it from ELB, see 1.**

The only possible solution I can see here and I am not sure if it is feasible:

Using CloudWatch mark the EC2 instance as unhealthy. ELB will stop distributing traffic to it. At the same time update the EC2 health for Auto Scaling manually:

```
aws autoscaling set-instance-health --instance-id i-123abc45d –-health-status healthy
```

This should override the health in a way that ELB will continue to ignore the EC2 instance and AWS Auto Scaling will not try to replace the instance. Would that work or is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you please clarify... You want to stop NEW connections going to the existing instances, but retain the CURRENT connections? Do you need to keep the current connections going indefinitely, rather than 60 minutes timeout? Have you tried removing an instance from an Auto Scaling group with `aws autoscaling detach-instances`?

Comment: Spot on @JohnRotenstein, that is exactly how it should work. Regarding your suggestion, see point 3. Unfortunately, in AWS it is tightly coupled, so removing it from the auto-scaling group also deregisters it from ELB. Other mechanisms like suspsend or remove temporarily seem to work in the same way.

Comment: Well, in that case you seem to have tried everything that's obvious (and even more!).

Comment: Your threshold is 2000 connections. Can I ask how you are getting this data? Is it a custom cloudwatch metric pushed from the instances? The key to AutoScaling is to scale up early. If you only scale when you've reached your max threshold, you're going to have a period of wait time before the auto scaling event can occur and your instance be brought into service. It's always advised to scale optimistically when your threshold starts getting close - eg. 1500 or 1700 connections.

Comment: @mickzer Yes, it's a custom metric and it is arbitrary, you're right, you should scale out earlier.